# Implementing webview and handling callbacks

Tags: typescript, android-webview, nativescript

Im trying to implement android webview in a nativescript app.

The webview is for handling prescriptions(refills/transfers) with the walgreens api.

The webview requires some logic to navigate it and handle callbacks.

They have a sample project which works so im trying to apply the logic they use on my app.

The parts im having trouble on is getting the transfer form to go past the first screen.

After I click on Next it just says error

Also on the refill screen its just blank.

On the sample app it shows an alert saying ‘Unable to refill your prescription now. Please contact the Pharmacist.’ which is what im trying to get to show

Below im attaching the sample project from walgreens and my attempt at implementing the webview.

The code im trying to implement is in the folder: \WAG_Rx_Demo_Android_v1.3_20150106\WAG_Rx_Demo_Android\src\com\walgreens\rx\screens

In my attempt i already have the webview html string that im trying to make work for the transfer and the refill screens.

These are the sample projects

[nativescript sample app attemp](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kpigY18j0TwVRQkL0Qj7vczKxoEvTHT_)

[walgreens sample app](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15lODqDBXTVhyKjkP6A9MDGgVKl2mAa6a)

This is the documentation ive been trying to follow as well
https://developer.walgreens.com/api/pharmacy-prescriptions/apimethod/pharmacy-prescription-api#HandleTransferCallbacks

https://developer.walgreens.com/api/pharmacy-prescriptions/apimethod/pharmacy-prescription-api#HandleRefillCallbacks

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the sample code in the documentation that explains in detail the handle callbacks section for android. You need to make sure you are handling the callback to the appCallback you set when you make your request to open the refill/transfer request. You can also reach out to our developer support email address (apibizdev@walgreens.com) for more information.